# For any real matrix $M$ let, $\lambda^{+}(M)$ be the number of positive eigenvalues of $M$ counting multiplicities.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For any real matrix $M$, let $\lambda^{+}(M)$ be the number of positive eigenvalues of $M$ counting multiplicities. Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix and $Q$ be an $n\times n$ real invertible matrix . Then which of the followings are correct?

(1) $rank(A)=rank(Q^{T}AQ)$

(2) $rank(A)=rank(Q^{-1}AQ)$

(3) $\lambda^{+}(A)=\lambda^{+}(Q^{T}AQ)$

(4) $\lambda^{+}(A)=\lambda^{+}(Q^{-1}AQ)$

Comment: We know the rank of A and Q^TAQ are same. But what is the similarities of the number of positive eigen values between A and Q^TAQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume $A$ is symmetric so we can find an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $v_{1}, . . . ,v_{n}$ with
eigenvalues $\lambda_{1}, . . .,\lambda_{n}$. Let $P$ be the orthogonal matrix formed by putting the $v_{j}$ as the columns. Then
$P^{T}AP=D$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $\lambda_{1}, . . .,\lambda_{n}$. Setting
$x=y_{1}v_{1}+ · · · + y_{n}v_{n}=Py$,
the quadratic form turns into a sum of squares:
$$Q(x)=x^{T}Ax=y^{T}P^{T}APy=y^{T}Dy=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{j}y_{j}^{2}.$$

From this representation, it is clear that $Q$ is positive definite if and only if all the eigenvalues are positive,

Answer (score 2):

From option 3 we can see that the given matrices are congruent and by Sylvester's law of inertia two congruent symmetric matrices have the same number of positive/ negative eigen values. For option 4, here two matrices are similar and so have same eigen values.